# How do i compare dates using difftime()?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int date_txt[5],today_date;

scanf("%d",&today_date);        //i enter (input) the date manually e.g. 20171109
date_txt[0]=20161102;           // year month day form (rrrrmmdd)
date_txt[1]=20150101;
date_txt[2]=20170615;
date_txt[3]=20160628;
date_txt[4]=20150101;
```

I have several dates which i need to compare with today_date to see if the difference is equal to or greater than 1 year. I have found that there exists a function for this called difftime(), but as i am a novice i do not know how to exactly do this. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `difftime()` reports the difference in seconds.  The numbers of seconds in a year varies (leap day).  Instead read input as text, parse into a `struct tm` and compare the members

Comment: no problem with the text part, but the parse into a struct tm lost me

Comment: `struct tm date; sscanf(buf, "%4d%2d%2d", &date.tm_year, ...`

Comment: Post what your have tried to parse the `int` and compare.  It could be quite simple and may not requite `struct tm`.

Comment: well i am reading from a text file and putting it into a char double array so the dates are in s[4],s[10],s[16],s[22],s[28] (strings, so if i wanted to printf s[28] it would print 20150101).

Comment: Or a simple as `if (today_date - date_txt[0] > 10000) puts("diff > 1 year");`

Comment: even if the are char and string types?

Comment: Posted code is not using `char` nor variables as string.  So "even if the are char and string types?" is unclear.

Comment: It is now working thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>

 #define COUNT 5
 #define SECONDS_NON_LEAP_YEAR (365*24*3600)
 #define SECONDS_LEAP_YEAR (366*24*3600)

 typedef struct tm T_TIME;
 T_TIME dToday, dTemp;

 void convertToTime(int iDate, T_TIME* tTime)
 {
    tTime->tm_mday = iDate%100;
    iDate/=100;
    tTime->tm_mon = (iDate%100)-1;
    iDate/=100;
    tTime->tm_year = iDate-1900;
 }

 int isLeapYear(int yyyy)
 {
    if(yyyy%100) // Not a century
    {
        return !(yyyy%4);
    }
    return !(yyyy%400);
 }

 int main(void) {
    int date_txt[]={20161102, 20150101, 20170615, 20160628, 20150101}; 
    int today_date, i, flg, isThisYearLeap, tSeconds;

    scanf("%d",&today_date); //i enter (input) the date manually e.g. 20171109 year month day form (rrrrmmdd)
    convertToTime(today_date, &dToday);
    isThisYearLeap = isLeapYear(dToday.tm_year+1900);

    for(i=0;i<COUNT; i++)
    {
        convertToTime(date_txt[i], &dTemp);
        tSeconds = difftime(mktime(&dToday), mktime(&dTemp));
        flg = (isThisYearLeap || isLeapYear(dTemp.tm_year+1900)) ?
            (tSeconds >= SECONDS_LEAP_YEAR) : (tSeconds >= SECONDS_NON_LEAP_YEAR);

        printf("The difference between Today and date %d is %s 1 year.\n", date_txt[i],
                    (flg ? "Greater than or equals to" : "Less than"));
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

See it in execution [here](https://ideone.com/ReDBPo)